# merge (video and sound) with (background music)

Tags: ffmpeg

i have video file vid.mpg that contain video and audio(speaking) and audio file aud.wav that contain background music.

now, i want to merge them together.

here is the command that i use:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mpg -i aud.mp3 -c:v copy  -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat = fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.1[1a];[0a][1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -t 0 out.mpg
```

and this is the error that i get as response:

```
[Parsed_amerge_4 @ 00000000003a36e0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_4 @ 00000000003a36e0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layou
t will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
```

in addition i add the full log:

```
C:\bina\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i vid.mpg -i
aud.mp3 -c:v copy  -filter_complex "[1:a]aform
at = fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.1[1a];[0a]
[1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -t 0 out.mpg
ffmpeg version N-78949-g6f5048f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenc
ore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --ena
ble-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable
-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --ena
ble-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx
264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable
-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 27.101 / 57. 27.101
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.100 /  6. 39.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'vid.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:33.62, start: 0.529978, bitrate: 22407 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:
1 DAR 16:9], max. 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000003e3c20] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 253.
Input #1, mp3, from 'aud.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
  Duration: 00:01:03.03, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.27
File 'out.mpg' already exists. Overwrite
 ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_amerge_4 @ 00000000003a36e0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_4 @ 00000000003a36e0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layou
t will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
Output #0, mpeg, to 'out.mpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-3
1, max. 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.27.101 mp2
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> aformat
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> aformat
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  amerge -> Stream #0:1 (mp2)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=234676 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=234676 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=236705 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=236705 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=238746 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=238746 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=240787 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=240787 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=242828 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=242828 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=244869 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=244869 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=246910 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=246910 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=248951 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=248951 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=250992 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=250992 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=253033 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=253033 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=255074 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=255074 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=257115 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=257115 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=259156 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=259156 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=261197 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=261197 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=263238 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=263238 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=265279 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=265279 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=267320 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=267320 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=269361 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=269361 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=271402 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=271402 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=273443 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=273443 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=275484 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=275484 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=277525 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=277525 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=279566 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=279566 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=281607 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=281607 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=283648 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=283648 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=285689 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=285689 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=287730 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=287730 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=289771 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=289771 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=291812 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=291812 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=293853 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=293853 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=295894 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=295894 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=297935 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=297935 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=299976 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=299976 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=302017 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=302017 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=304058 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=304058 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=306099 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=306099 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=308140 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=308140 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=310181 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=310181 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=312222 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=312222 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=314263 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=314263 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=316304 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=316304 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=318345 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=318345 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=320386 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=320386 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=322427 size=322616
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 000000000289a4e0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=322427 size=322616
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     318kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
  0x
video:315kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: 0.934858%

C:\bina\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i vid.mpg -i
aud.mp3 -c:v copy  -filter_complex "[0:a]aform
at = fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.1[1a];[0a]
[1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -t 0 out.mpg
```

what am i doing wrong? and how can i solve it?

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mpg -i aud.mp3 -c:v copy 
       -filter_complex
        "[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];
         [1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.1[1a];
         [0a][1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -f dvd out.mpg
```

The standard MPEG PS muxer in ffmpeg is MPEG-1 Systems. For MPEG-2, you need to specify `-f dvd`.

In the console output you posted, the command applies the `aformat` twice to the same input and not at all to the other. That should explain the layout warning.